# CUDA multiple architecture compilation shuffle functions

Tags: cuda

I am using `__shfl*` functions in a CUDA code and also using replacement (slower) functions for compatibility with CUDA devices < Cuda capability 3.0.

My header file is like below before I actually use `__shfl*` functions.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#define _SR_MAX_BLOCK (512)
#if !defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) || __CUDA_ARCH__ < 300
...
... replacement functions defined here
...
#endif

...
... __shfl* functions used here
```

My `nvcc` argument for multi-architecture compile is as follows:

```
-gencode arch=compute_20,code="sm_20,compute_20";-gencode arch=compute_20,code="sm_21,
compute_20";-gencode arch=compute_30,code="sm_30,compute_30";-gencode arch=compute_35,
code="sm_35,compute_35";-gencode arch=compute_52,code="sm_52,compute_52"
```

`Question`: Does nvcc compile separate codes for separate architectures? If so, am I guaranteed that the slower replacement codes will be executed only when the runtime CUDA device has capability lesser than 3.0 and that the fast intrinsic shuffle functions be used otherwise?

Comment: cuda compiles a separate codepath for each `-gencode` switch you provide.  That code path may consist of either SASS or PTX code (or both), but it will target the architecture specified in your gencode switch.  As to your second question, something like what you have shown should give you what you want, but the exact arrangement you have shown is not not what I would use.  It would be useful if your example code would show at least the function prototype arrangement, so others could guide you.  Does this: `#define _SR_MAX_BLOCK (512)` have anything to do with your question?

Comment: If you simply built a test case using what you have shown, I think you could discover for yourself that it will not work exactly as you have shown.  The compiler will throw errors on the use of shuffle functions for cc2.0 codepaths, because your shuffle function definitions have no conditional compilation structure to prevent their compilation in a cc2.0 codepath, according to what you have shown.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I am already using `#if !defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) || __CUDA_ARCH__ < 300` as that condition. So, when `__shfl*` is undefined i.e. `__CUDA_ARCH__ < 300`, the replacement `__shfl*` definitions will be used. I am wondering how this `if` conditional is triggered. Is it triggered only once or, multiple times, once for each gencode?

Comment: There is a full preprocessor pass for each architecture you pass to nvcc. So if it isn't working you need a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

> Question: Does nvcc compile separate codes for separate architectures?

Yes

> If so, am I guaranteed that the slower replacement codes will be
>   executed only when the runtime CUDA device has capability lesser than
>   3.0 and that the fast intrinsic shuffle functions be used otherwise?

Code within the pragma #ifdef block will only be compiled for architectures that meet that conditional. With your compile line you'll get a different compilation pass for each architecture that you listed.

Comment: ["Separate compilation"](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/) has a distinct meaning which does not apply in this case, thus the edit.